# Cannot resolve getSystemService in Fragment in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a navigation Drawer which has a Map in a Fragment. Here is my code.

Here is the `fragment_map.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.myayubo.FragmentMap">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCity"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then I called FragmentMap in my `ExtractMenu.java`

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentMap();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

Then in `FragmentMap.java` following code was added to Zoom the ,ap to current location.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // Identify the current location of the device
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this); // change the place when the device is moving

        Location currentLocation = getMyLocation(); // Calling the getMyLocation method

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_map, container, false);
    }



 // Implement getMyLocation

        public Location getMyLocation() {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); // Get location from GPS if it's available
            Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // Location wasn't found, check the next most accurate place for the current location
            if (myLocation == null) {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                // Finds a provider that matches the criteria
                String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                // Use the provider to get the last known location
                myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            }
            return myLocation;
        }
```

Here I cannot resolve `getSystemService` Any one knows why? Is there any better way to Zoom the Map in Fragment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> getActivity() in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is
>   currently associated with.

You are using **Fragment**, So you need to add `getActivity()` .I hope it will helps you .

**Finally** ,

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.ExtractMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)

Comment: @Manu this is another case

Comment: Okay. Thanks to the answer. It solved my problem anyway :)

Comment: @Manu Glad to hear . Move ahead

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

For `Fragment`:

```
getActivity().getSystemService()
```

For `Activity` :

```
getSystemService()
```

so for your code it will be

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    LocationManager lm = LocationManager.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```