# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

pls help. my app crashes when i open my application on my fragment. i am using a navigation drawer.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at johnbea.com.mysystem.LanlordMapFragment.onCreateView(LanlordMapFragment.java:68)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

here is the code on navigation drawer before going to the map fragment

```
 private void displaySelectedScreen(int ID){

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (ID){
        case R.id.add_apartment:
            fragment = LandlordAddApartment.newInstance(id, username);
            FragmentManager addfragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            addfragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            break;
        case R.id.reserve_request:
            fragment = new LandlordReservation();
            break;
        case R.id.ver_request:
            fragment = LandlordVerification.newInstance(id, username);
            FragmentManager verificationfragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
            verificationfragment.beginTransaction();
            break;
        case R.id.landlord_log_out:
            fragment = LandlordLogout.newInstance(id, username);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            break;
        case R.id.map2:
            fragment = new LanlordMapFragment();

    }
    if(fragment != null){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_landlord, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

here is my fragment where the google map.. im getting trouble with getting the current location on this fragment. it already took me 2 weeks already still i cant figure it out.. can someone please help me :(

```
   @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("MAP");

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, (android.location.LocationListener) getActivity());
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



/*@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;


    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.137769, 123.743652)).title("Legazpi property").snippet("asdasdasd"));
    CameraPosition legazpi =   CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(13.137769, 123.743652)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(legazpi));

   // LatLng legazpi = new LatLng(-13.137769, 123.743652);
 //   mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(legazpi).title("Legazpi property"));
  //  mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(legazpi));


        //return;

    }
```

*/

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView locationTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: Why `onMapReady` is commented out? Do anything you want with map after this method is called otherwise you'll get NPE.

Answer (score 0):

John its because of `mGoogleMap` isn't initialized yet so its null. You need to call `onMapReady` function. And in `onMapReady` function use  `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` .

Comment: i already tried calling the mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); on the onMapReady but it wont get my current location

Comment: Tha'ts different thing, But this solution will remove your crash.

Answer (score 0):

use `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` inside public void `onMapReady` after initialing map like

```
onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
   mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

if you don't want map remove `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Comment: i use this as a reference.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525632/cannot-resolve-getsystemservice-in-fragment-in-navigation-drawer he didnt call the setmylocation on the onMapReay..  but on the OnCreateView

Comment: That question has already some issue. Don't use such Question for your code. you have to call onMapReady(). and implement map related method inside it after initialising  mGoogleMap = googleMap;